# How to add an model instance to a django queryset?

Tags: python, django

It seems like a django queryset behaves somehow like a python list.

But it doesn't support list's .append() method as I know.

What I want to do is like:

```
from my_django_app.models import MyModel

queryset = MyModel.objects.none()
queryset.append(MyModel.objects.first())      ## no list's .append() method!
```

Is there any way to add an model instance to an existing queryset?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can also use the `|` operator to create a union:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.none()
instance = MyModel.objects.first()
queryset |= MyModel.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk)
```

But be warned that this will generate different queries depending on the number of items you append this way, making caching of compiled queries inefficient.

Comment: Can anyone suggest more efficient manner for this?

Comment: Depends on what you need. E.g. do you have many instances to add? Maybe `.filter(pk__in=...)` works for you.

Answer (score 32):

No. A queryset is a representation of a *query* - hence the name - not an arbitrary collection of instances.

If you really need an actual queryset rather than a list, you could try accumulating the IDs of the objects you need and then getting the objects via an `__in` query:

```
list_of_ids = []
list_of_ids.append(my_id)
...
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=list_of_ids)
```

This isn't very efficient, though.

Comment: Why is this one disagreeing with the others? Not qute following why both have substantial + votes

Answer (score 21):

This can be done using `union`. After doing this, the type of the result can be seen as `<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>`. So two querysets can be combined. Lets see an example.

```
query1 = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)

query2 = User.objects.filter(is_active=False)

combined_query = query1.union(query2)

print (type(combined_query))
```

The above program will print result as below, confirming it is a queryset

```
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

---

So basically Django executes the below query for union.

```
(SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."is_active" = True) 
UNION 
(SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."is_active" = False)
```

---

*This also means that there will be error(`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: each UNION query must have the same number of columns`) if union is tried with two different tables.*

Comment: Beware: the `QuerySet` returned by `union()` has limitations. For example, it cannot be `filter`ed again. See [union documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#union) for details. Also see my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62764662).

Comment: For a reason I do not fully understand, calling `.union(qs2)` was the solution for me. Using the `|` operator seemed to create a brand new query combining the existing two, which resulted in a different result than just the union.

Answer (score 8):

Queryset is not a `list`

So

```
to_list = queryset.values()
```

To combine `queryset`

```
from itertools import chain
result_queryset = list(chain(queryset1, queryset2))
```

**or**

```
querysets = [queryset1, queryset2]
result_queryset = list(chain(*querysets))
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to accumulate some model instances to an queryset and return the queryset rather than an python list. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You are eventually getting an _list_ (`result_queryset`), not a _queryset_.

Comment: does not work, getting exception that it is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

I did now and I got it. Use filter to take multiple ids. Use get only takes a single element. For example, if you have a queryset called Product with many products already registered, that is, with several id's. Do:

```py
a= list(Product.objects.filter(id=7)) 
b= list(Product.objects.filter(id__in=['3','5'])) 
a.append(b) 
print(a)
```