# How to check if value occurs in a field of a model list in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a list of Django models, I want to check if a string value occurs somewhere in a specific field for ANY model in the list. Please see the example below:

```
class something:
    animals = [] #type: list[Animals]

   def does_atleast_one_animal_make_that_sound(animal_sound):
       if animal_sound in ...# for each animal in animals, turn animal.sound into a list
            print('One of the animals in the list makes this sound')
       else:
            print('No animal makes this sound')
```

How would I correctly write the part of the function with the "..."?

Answer (score 3):

If model instances are presented in the db, you can use any of the listed approaches (first and second are based on the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29587771/8755105)):

1) Queryset's [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
class something:
    animals = [] #type: list[Animals]
    animals = [animal.id for animal in animals]

    def does_atleast_one_animal_make_that_sound(animal_sound):
       if animal_sound in Animal.objects.filter(id__in=animals).values_list('sound', flat=True):
            print('One of the animals in the list makes this sound')
       else:
            print('No animal makes this sound')
```

2) Even better if you use [`exists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists):

```
class something:
    animals = [] #type: list[Animals]
    animals = [animal.id for animal in animals]

    def does_atleast_one_animal_make_that_sound(animal_sound):
       if Animal.objects.filter(id__in=animals, sound=animal_sound).exists():
            print('One of the animals in the list makes this sound')
       else:
            print('No animal makes this sound')
```

3) If models were only constructed (`Animal(...)`), but not saved to the db, then you can use pure python filtering:

```
class something:
    animals = [] #type: list[Animals]

   def does_atleast_one_animal_make_that_sound(animal_sound):
       if any(filter(lambda animal: animal.sound == animal_sound, animals)):
            print('One of the animals in the list makes this sound')
       else:
            print('No animal makes this sound')
```

**Note**: it is usually better to delegate model instances filtering to the database (talking about the origin of `animals` variable). In this case the 3rd option seems the best as it does not require to query the database.

Comment: Doesn't this check all my models in the DB? The only animals I want included are the ones in the animals list defined at the top. Is there a way to do this with only those ones?

For example, lets say animals =  [Cow, Chicken], but my DB Animal models has [Cow,Chicken,Dog]. In your function, 'woof' would return true, but I want 'woof' to return false because its not in my list