# How can i add a user to a query set of users

Tags: django

I was getting all the users of following in which all user present except the logged-in one.

```
def FeedListView(request):
    my_users=request.user.following.all()
    my_users.append(request.user)
    print(my_users)
    query=FeedDetail.objects.filter(user__in=my_users)
    return render(request,'feed/feed_list.html',{'objects':query})
```

I can't append the query list but for query i also want it to filter for requested user thatare not present in my_users 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Phillip Watts is correct but it use 2 queries.
If you are concerned with efficiency, you could use the [Q operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q)

```
from django.db.models import Q
FeedDetail.objects.filter(
    Q(user=request.user) 
    | Q(user__in=request.user.following.all())
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to append the ***User Ids*** instead of their objects/querset.

```
def FeedListView(request):
    my_users_id = list(request.user.following.all().values_list('id', flat=True))
    my_users_id.append(request.user.id)
    query = FeedDetail.objects.filter(user__id__in=my_users_id)
    return render(request, 'feed/feed_list.html', {'objects': query})
```

**Reference**:
1. SO post - [How to add an model instance to a django queryset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587382/how-to-add-an-model-instance-to-a-django-queryset)
2. [**`values_list()`** -- [Django Doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Answer (score -1):

You need to turn the queryset into a list first, something like this:

```
def FeedListView(request):
    my_users_list = list(request.user.following.all())
    my_users_list.append(request.user)
    print(my_users_list)
    query=FeedDetail.objects.filter(user__in=my_users_list)
    return render(request,'feed/feed_list.html',{'objects':query})
```

Comment: ^ This creates a list of IDs. You can also create a list of the objects with something like, my_users_list = list(my_users) -> my_users_list.append(request.user) -> query=FeedDetail.objects.filter(user__in=my_users_list)

Comment: converting it by list(my_users) it worked as expected . Thank you so much

Comment: If this has worked can you mark as the correct answer?

Comment: `QuerySet.values_list()` doesn't return a `list` but another `QuerySet`, and you discard the result anyway, so your code is the very same (non working) code as what the OP posted, with just one totally useless operation added.