# Adding manually an entry to the Django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

This is my model (the relevant part):

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, choices=COUNTRY_NAME_CHOICE)
    country_id = models.CharField(max_length=500,choices=COUNTRY_ID_CHOICE,primary_key=True,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500,choices=CITY_NAME_CHOICE)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    zip= models.CharField(max_length=500, choices=ZIP_CHOICE, primary_key=True,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Cost(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey('Date' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city= models.ForeignKey('City' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    entry_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return  self.city.name + ' ' +str(self.value)
```

For model Cost, I have a Django form CostForm that I am listing out on a template, so that users can insert new costs.

```
class CostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cost
        exclude = ['user','entry_time']             

    #Makes only FR, NO, and RU cities available 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['city'].queryset = City.objects.filter(country__name__in=['France','Norway','Russia'])
```

On the template city field is shown as a dropdown. I have already managed to limit this field to the values I want in the form above (user can input costs only for Russia, Norway and France, because their cities are the only options they see in the dropdown).

> Here is my problem: I need to make another option available for the
>   users in the city dropdown. A city that doesn't exist for real in the
>   database. Lets call it "X". When user chooses city X, that would be a
>   sign that I need to do some additional calculations in the backend, and
>   split up cost between some other cities.

I thought I could manually add this city X to the queryset in the CostForm, but after some extensive research I hit the wall. Everyone is saying that the queryset object is not there to be edited, but only represents the result of a query.
Then I tried editing the dropdown in javascript and adding a new option for city X there, and I managed, BUT, I cannot work with this entry with city X, because the form is not valid. So, the user just gets the message similar to "Please choose a valid option for the field".
So now I am back to exploring the possibility of adding this city X manually to the queryset in the CostForm... Does anyone know how?? Also, if you have any other ideas on how I could solve this problem, please share.

Comment: You can try making a new Queryset and set it to `mutable=True` then update the queryset with the new city data and then save that updated data to the database. If this sounds close to what you're looking for I can provide a snippet as an answer.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587382/how-to-add-an-model-instance-to-a-django-queryset) discussion. It contains some interesting ideas.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! @KevinHernandez The thing is that I don't want to save this city X in the database. I am connecting this city table to other tables in my db, and I wouldn't want it to show X as an option anywhere else. It should just be a sign for me to do the calculations in the backend when the user chooses the city X. But, this mutable=True does sound interesting, maybe it could help...

Comment: @FotisSk I saw this discussion, but I am looking for a way to edit the queryset in the code, not to create a union of two querysets.

Comment: @GileBrt You can try importing QueryDict from `django.http` as `from django.http import QueryDict` Then creating your own QueryDict with `myquery = QueryDict(mutable=True)` and then updating that mutable query with the new data with `myquery.update(newdata)`. `newdata` being the modified data where you add your city.

Comment: @KevinHernandez Thanks, I'll check it out!