# How to use Django QuerySet.union() in ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany()?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset

Not sure what I am doing wrong here:

I tried to use [QuerySet.union()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#union), in Django 2.2.10, to combine two querysets (for the same model) inside `ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany()`. However, when the form is saved, the entire queryset is selected, regardless of the actual selection made.

Please consider the minimal example below, based on the standard Django [Article/Publication example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin


class Publication(models.Model):
    pass


class Article(models.Model):
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(to=Publication, blank=True)


class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'publications':
            # the following query makes no sense, but it shows an attempt to
            # combine two separate QuerySets using QuerySet.union()
            kwargs['queryset'] = Publication.objects.all().union(
                Publication.objects.all())
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)


admin.site.register(Publication)
admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

The initial `queryset` for the `publications` field is filtered using `formfield_for_manytomany`, as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany).

PLEASE NOTE: The actual query in this example makes no sense, it just returns everything, but that's not important: the point is that `QuerySet.union()` messes up the selection. It works normally if you remove the `union()`.

Here's what happens when I add a new `Article` in the admin, *without selecting any publications*:

Before "Save" (nothing selected)

[image]

After "Save" (everything is selected)

[image]

No matter what I do, all options are automatically selected every time the form is saved.

Am I using `QuerySet.union()` the wrong way, or is this expected behavior, given the [restrictions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#union) on querysets returned by `QuerySet.union()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @tom-carrick pointed out, it appears that a `QuerySet` returned by `QuerySet.union()` cannot be filtered. I suppose this is implied by the following excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#union):

> In addition, only `LIMIT`, `OFFSET`, `COUNT(*)`, `ORDER BY`, and specifying columns (i.e. slicing, `count()`, `order_by()`, and `values()`/`values_list()`) are allowed on the resulting `QuerySet`.

If you're using Django 3.0, calling `filter()` on the result of `QuerySet.union()` will raise an exception with a pretty clear message:

```
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Calling QuerySet.filter() after union() is not supported.
```

However, no exception is raised if you're using Django 2.2: In that case it just returns the complete queryset, regardless of the filter arguments. Here's a little test to illustrate that (in Django 2.2):

```
# using Django 2.2.10
class PublicationTests(TestCase):
    def test_union_filter(self):
        for i in range(2):
            Publication.objects.create()
        queryset_union = Publication.objects.filter(id=1).union(
            Publication.objects.filter(id=2))
        self.assertEqual(2, len(queryset_union))
        for obj in queryset_union.all():
            self.assertIn(obj, queryset_union.filter(id=1))
            self.assertIn(obj, queryset_union.filter())
            self.assertIn(obj, queryset_union.filter(id=0))
```

So, this must be what happens when we use `QuerySet.union()` to restrict a queryset in the `ModelAdmin`: The selection widget works as expected, but when the form is validated, `filter()` is called on the output of `QuerySet.union()` (see [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/forms/models.py#L1321) for the `ModelMultipleChoiceField`), and that always returns the complete queryset, regardless of the actual subselection.

Depending on the actual use case, there may be ways around using `union()`, as explained in [tom-carrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62758600).

However, there is at least one way to work around the restrictions imposed by `QuerySet.union()` in this situation, and that is to create a new queryset from the queryset-union:

Here's a modified version of the `ArticleAdmin` from the original example:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'publications':
            queryset_union = Publication.objects.all().union(
                Publication.objects.all())
            kwargs['queryset'] = Publication.objects.filter(id__in=queryset_union)
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Again, the actual query in this contrived example makes no sense, but that is not important here.

This might not be the most efficient solution in terms of database access.

Answer (score 5):

The problem does seem to be `.union()`, though I can't figure out why. It seems like a bug, or at least funky behaviour.

Since you don't specify your actual use-case, it's hard to know, but for the example you give you can use the `OR` operator instead, which will work for that:

```py
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'publications':
            # the following query makes no sense, but it shows an attempt to
            # combine two separate QuerySets using QuerySet.union()
            kwargs['queryset'] = (
                Publication.objects.filter(id__lt=3)
                | Publication.objects.filter(id__gt=2)
            )
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but, as mentioned explicitly in the question, (see the "PLEASE NOTE" part, *and* the comment in the example code), I know the query makes no sense because it includes everything. That's not what the question is about: the point is that everything is not only shown, but everything is also *selected*.

Comment: In that case I suggest you come up with MREs that are more representative of your problem. When you change the queryset in this way, you're also changing the default for if you don't select anything when adding an object - you're not simply changing what is displayed. The admin doesn't seem to display this very well. I'm not sure if it's a bug or if it's intentional, but the UX isn't very good, at least.

Comment: I've edited with another go. It looks like you can do this if an OR query will work just as well. It seems like there is a bug in Django.

Comment: Actually my goal here is to understand why `union` cannot be used to filter the admin queryset. (Also to point this fact out to others.) Actually your initial answer did contain a good point in the last paragraph: If a `QuerySet` cannot be filtered after `union()`, then the observed behavior makes a bit more sense. Perhaps this is implied in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#union) for `union()`, but it would still be nice to know *where* exactly this goes wrong in the admin source.

Comment: I'm not sure that's especially relevant, because that raises an exception / yellow page when it happens. What's surprising to me is why if you select nothing, everything is added.

Comment: It think it is relevant: `some_queryset.union(other_queryset).filter(id=1)` returns the complete union of the two querysets, without raising any exception. So the `filter()` fails silently. For those interested: the queryset is indeed filtered during form validation: see [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/forms/models.py#L1321)

Comment: Based on your suggestion I modified the example a bit, now just using `all()`. Hope that makes it a bit more clear. Thanks for the fruitful discussion. :-)

Comment: It's indeed just a bug, there is already a patch, so presumably it will be fixed in the next bugfix release: https://github.com/django/django/pull/13158

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the "(excuse the bizarre example filtering)" in your [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31767)...

Comment: Using `filter()` after `union()` raises an exception in Django 3.0, but it does not in Django 2.2.